# Bidirectional recognition of basic algebra postulates in symbolic computing

Tags: python, logic, sympy, symbolic-math, sage

On some symbolic computation frameworks like Sage, I define 'a=b+c' and when query for 'a' I get 'b+c' for result as expected. But when I query for 'b' I get 'b' instead of 'a-c' and 'b' together. Following the same logic with the definition of 'k=m' ; I expect to get result 'k' and 'm' for the query of 'm'. One variable can be part of other variables and when I probe my variable I want itself and all it's associations be listed at output. What is the defacto term for the case I attempted to explain ? There should be at least a way to achieve this without defining each combination of variables.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `a = b` doesn't have the effect of telling the system about some logical relationship between variables. All it does is assign the Python variable `a` to the value of `b`. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols (it works basically the same way in Sage too). Understanding the difference between a symbolic symbol and a programming language variable is essential here.  In Python (which is what Sage and SymPy use), `=` assigns to programming language variables. It has no mathematical meaning.

To represent a mathematical equality, you need to use `==` in Sage, or `Eq()` in SymPy. If you want to get representations of symbols in terms of others, you should use `solve()`. For instance, in SymPy.

```
>>> a, b, c, k, m = symbols('a b c k m')
>>> eq1 = Eq(a, b + c)
>>> eq2 = Eq(k, m)
>>> solve([eq1, eq2], b)
{b: a - c}
>>> solve([eq1, eq2], m)
{m: k}
```

Comment: In Sage I think solve function operates on numerical values only. For SymPy your solution works ; at Sage I do a==b+c instead of Eq(a,b+c) solve returns no output.

Comment: I guess Sage uses a different syntax. You should consult its documentation.